# Networkcard errors after upgrade from squeeze to jessie

Tags: linux, debian, network-adapter

We upgraded one of our central routers, which was horribly outdated, via `apt-get dist-upgrade` from Debian Squeeze over Wheezy to Jessie.

But now we see the following errors in `dmesg`:

```
[Tue Apr 12 22:17:55 2016] e1000 0000:09:03.0 wi22: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <2>
  TDT                  <5b>
  next_to_use          <5b>
  next_to_clean        <0>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <3abbd6>
  next_to_watch        <4>
  jiffies              <3abd34>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
[Tue Apr 12 22:17:57 2016] e1000 0000:09:03.0 wi22: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <2>
  TDT                  <5b>
  next_to_use          <5b>
  next_to_clean        <0>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <3abbd6>
  next_to_watch        <4>
  jiffies              <3abf29>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
[Tue Apr 12 22:17:59 2016] e1000 0000:09:03.0 wi22: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <2>
  TDT                  <5b>
  next_to_use          <5b>
  next_to_clean        <0>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <3abbd6>
  next_to_watch        <4>
  jiffies              <3ac11e>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:01 2016] e1000 0000:09:03.0 wi22: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <2>
  TDT                  <5b>
  next_to_use          <5b>
  next_to_clean        <0>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <3abbd6>
  next_to_watch        <4>
  jiffies              <3ac313>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] e1000 0000:09:03.0 wi22: Reset adapter
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br50: port 2(wi22.50) entered disabled state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br60: port 2(wi22.60) entered disabled state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br161: port 1(wi22.161) entered disabled state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br170: port 7(wi22.170) entered disabled state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] e1000: wi22 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br50: port 2(wi22.50) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br50: port 2(wi22.50) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br60: port 2(wi22.60) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br60: port 2(wi22.60) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br161: port 1(wi22.161) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br161: port 1(wi22.161) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br170: port 7(wi22.170) entered forwarding state
[Tue Apr 12 22:18:03 2016] br170: port 7(wi22.170) entered forwarding state
```

This happens for all interfaces, which are 1Gbit fibre optic, around every 2 seconds.

Some users even reported an unstable connection.

What does that mean? Is it because of outdated hardware?

We are planning to buy a new one, but how can we solve the problem until the new router is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error might be a bug in the current kernel.

https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/432/

We downgraded the kernel to `3.2.0-4` and it works again.